# How does UILabel vertically center its text?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uilabel, typography

There has been a lot of confusion about what I am actually trying to achieve. So please let me reword my question. It is as simple as:

> How does Apple center text inside `UILabel`'s `-drawTextInRect:`?

---

Here's some context on why I am looking for Apple's approach to center text:

- I am not happy with how they center text inside this method
- I have my own algorithm that does the job the way I want

However, there are some places I can't inject this algorithm into, not even with method swizzling. Getting to know the exact algorithm they use (or an equivalent of that) would solve my personal problem.

---

Here's a [demo project](https://github.com/jenox/UILabel/blob/master/Sources/AppleLabel.m#L16) you can experiment with. In case you're interested what my problem with Apple's implementation is, look at the left side (base UILabel): The text jumps up and down as you increase the font size using the slider, instead of gradually moving downwards.

Again, all I am looking for is an implementation of `-drawTextInRect:` that does the very same as base `UILabel` -- but without calling `super`.

```
- (void)drawTextInRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGRect const centeredRect = ...;

    [self.attributedText drawInRect:centeredRect];
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I missed the point! just deleted my post

Comment: Do you mean you want to change the text bounds? Or do you actually want to implement -drawTextInRect? Seems like 2 different questions.

Comment: I want to subclass `UILabel` and override `-drawTextInRect:`, but it should behave exactly like `UILabel` does.

Comment: If you want to use core text or NSLayoutManager to draw text, go for it, but if you are not changing the rendering specifically why re-invent the wheel?

Comment: Because I am changing rendering. I have to revert what Apple has done beforehand though, hence I'm trying to understand what crime they are committing in `UILabel`.

Comment: got it. Is your UILabel multiline?

Comment: Nope, but I wouldn't mind getting a solution for both. :)

Comment: Can NSStringDrawingContext.totalBounds give you the information you need? (Admittedly, that would be after drawing.)

Comment: if you want to override the -drawTextInRect i can post the custom class which will override that.

Comment: @whybird No, `context.totalBounds.size.height` generally returns the same value as `[text sizeWithAttributes:attributes].height`.

Comment: @MaheshAgrawal Sharing is caring.

Comment: @ChristianSchnorr You want to do what if like this: https://www.dropbox.com/s/5yh75qd2yj1xnee/TestLabel.zip?dl=0

Comment: @Bannings Nice interactive idea. If you add a UILabel side by side, you'll be able to tell [it's a little off](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3722472/Coding/Objective-C/TestLabel.zip) though.

Comment: i asked because no one posted answer. please see my answer if it will help you.

Comment: Can you give an example of text that is not centred vertically in a UILabel? And I assume that you are taking descenders into account?

Comment: If your requirement is to only keep your text centered, when sizing the text, would it work for you? http://www.justbeamit.com/pqfid

Comment: @Shoaib Your download no longer exists.

Comment: @MichaelL Not that it does anything to the subject of my question, but a [41.8 point system font (iOS 8) in a 39.5 point height container is off by a pixel](https://s3.amazonaws.com/f.cl.ly/items/2r0y2k1t042W0x1T2b3w/UILabel.png), for example.

Comment: @ChristianSchnorr check this link http://www.filedropper.com/screenrecording

Comment: @Shoaib Yeah, something like that. Now put a UILabel side by side and check if they are the same.

Comment: @ChristianSchnorr, what do you mean by side by side? can you plz make it more clear?

Comment: @Shoaib Check my [sample project](https://github.com/jenox/UILabel/blob/master/Sources/AppleLabel.m#L16) or my own answer.

Comment: Have you checked `lineHeight`?

Comment: @Sulthan Yes I did. Feel free to play around with it though.

Comment: A screenshot of incorrectly centred test would be helpful. As it is this question doesn't adequately explain what you perceive the problem to be.

Comment: @Tommy I have included a screenshot already, see [here](https://s3.amazonaws.com/f.cl.ly/items/2r0y2k1t042W0x1T2b3w/UILabel.png). As to why I perceive this to be a problem does not matter. I want to understand how apple achieves this behavior, as stated in my question.

Comment: I've also spent plenty days trying to align `UILabel`s pixel-perfect in the vertical axis. The vertical padding in `UILabel` is really weird. Debugging `UILabel`, `UIFont` and other text-related classes all day did not help. In the end I gave up and made my own label class which we now use throughout the app… I'm really looking forward to iOS 9 as they said that they fixed the issue - at least for auto layout.

Comment: @ChristianSchnorr It's a bit heavy but you could swizzle `UILabel`s default `drawTextInRect:` and also add an own property to all `UILabel`s which defines whether to use your own implementation or the default one. That way you can use your own drawing in any `UILabel` instance, e.g. by using `label.useCustomDrawing = YES;`. -- You could also make a simple subclass of `UILabel` (which must not have any stored properties) and then replace the class of the label you want to modify (and cannot instantiate on your own) at runtime: `object_setClass(evilLabel, MyCoolLabel.class);`

Comment: @fluidsonic And on top of that it would not even solve my root problem: `UITextField` does some weird stuff in its field editor *while editing*. I figured its the very same algorithm as in `UILabel`, but there's no AppStore-safe way to reach that.

Comment: @ChristianSchnorr then use private API. We have no problem using private API if Apple limited us in a stupid way like that. You just need to cover your private API usage and make sure it recovers nicely when the private API changes. We do that for years now and did not have a single rejection.

Comment: @fluidsonic I am not willing to do so.

Comment: @ChristianSchnorr tried to contact Apple dev support to get help here? They are the only ones with enough insight on how to layout this properly.

Comment: @ChristianSchnorr as I clearly said, it's unclear *what* you think the problem is. Not why it bothers you. I'll put your tightly cropped copy of the text 'Lorem' into your question on the assumption that this makes sense to somebody. EDIT: and, to be explicit about it, the text in the image you have supplied **is vertically centred**. The gaps between either extent of the text and the cropped box given are the same.

Comment: @Tommy I don't care if you understand the problem I have with the way Apple centers the text or *if there even is a problem* with it -- maybe I am just weird. But it is in no correlation to my question. I want to reproduce Apple's algorithm. As for the image I already stated that its '41.8 point system font (iOS 8) in a 39.5 point height container is off by a pixel'. **EDIT:** no it is not centered. You have 9 pixels below, 10.5 above. Having 10 below and 9.5 above would be more centered.

Comment: @ChristianSchnorr "I don't care if you understand the problem"; okay, got it. I'm not surprised you've had to add a bounty if you don't care whether those reading your problem understand it. Good luck getting an answer.

Comment: @Tommy You just don't understand. Maybe there is no problem with the way Apple centers the text. **But this was not my question.** I asked how to reproduce this behavior.

Comment: @ChristianSchnorr at least you've understood my question this time, which clearly stated that, no, it's completely unclear to me what you think the problem is. Your question currently has: four deleted answers, one with two down votes and two with no votes whatsoever. I'm not aware of any other question with even just that number of deleted answers. So, empirically, it seems an overwhelming majority of people don't understand what you think the problem is. If you think that's everyone else having a comprehension problem then so be it.

Comment: @Tommy That's the reason why I added an own example answer. Also the edit you made the my post would just confuse people more, because it implies that I care about the centering in the image, which again, **I do not**. It would just lead people in the wrong direction. I do not care about centering text. I want to understand Apple's attempt at doing so.

Comment: @ChristianSchnorr if you think the question is sufficiently well explained then let it run and enjoy the answers you get. Right now I'm looking at, amongst other things, a question that says "For quite some time I have been annoyed by the fact that text in various Apple views is not properly vertically centered." and a comment that says "Also the edit you made the my post would just confuse people more, because it implies that I care about the centering in the image, which again, **I do not**." I'd suggest you're really not being as clear as you think you are.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80787/discussion-between-christian-schnorr-and-tommy).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After two years and a week at WWDC I finally figured out what the hell is going on.

As for why `UILabel` behaves the way it does: It looks like Apple attempts to center whatever lies between [ascender and descender](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-fv9mYiQjylg/Tq7ZS1soCGI/AAAAAAAAAJc/DpcXD2eUHxI/s1600/typeface-anatomy.gif). However, the actual text drawing engine always snaps the baseline to pixel boundaries. If one doesn't pay attention to this when calculating the rect in which to draw the text, the baseline may jump up and down seemingly arbitrarily.

---

The main problem is finding where Apple places the baseline. AutoLayout offers a firstBaselineAnchor, but it's value can unfortunately not be read from code. The following snippet appears to correctly predict the baseline at all screen `scale`s and `contentScaleFactor`s as long as the label's height is rounded to pixels.

```
extension UILabel {
    public var predictedBaselineOffset: CGFloat {
        let scale = self.window?.screen.scale ?? UIScreen.main.scale

        let availablePixels = round(self.bounds.height * scale)
        let preferredPixels = ceil(self.font.lineHeight * scale)
        let ascenderPixels = round(self.font.ascender * scale)
        let offsetPixels = ceil((availablePixels - preferredPixels) / 2)

        return (ascenderPixels + offsetPixels) / scale
    }
}
```

When the label's height is not rounded to pixels, the predicted baseline is a pixel off more often than not, e.g. for a 13.0pt font in 40.1pt container on a 2x device or a 16.0pt font in 40.1pt container on a 3x device.

Note that we **have to** work at pixel level here. Working with points (i.e. dividing by screen scale immediately rather than at the end) results in off-by-one errors on @3x screens due to floating point inaccuracies.

For example, centering a 47px (15.667pt) content in a 121px container (40.333pt) gives us a 12.333pt offset which gets ceiled to 12.667pt due to floating point errors.

---

For sake of answering the question I initially asked, we can then implement `-drawTextInRect:` using the (hopefully correctly) predicted baseline to yield the same results as `UILabel` does.

```
public class AppleImitatingLabel: UILabel {
    public override func drawText(in rect: CGRect) {
        let offset = self.predictedBaselineOffset
        let frame = rect.offsetBy(dx: 0, dy: offset)

        self.attributedText!.draw(with: frame, options: [], context: nil)
    }
}
```

See the [project on GitHub](https://github.com/jenox/UILabel) for a working implementation.

Comment: @TomvanZummeren That's true, I haven't played around with those. I'm confident that the same logic applies though: you only need to adjust what currently is `self.font.lineHeight` to account for multiple lines being drawn.

Answer (score 8):

I don't have an answer, but I did a little research and thought I'd share it.  I used [Xtrace](https://github.com/johnno1962/Xtrace), which lets you trace Objective-C method calls, to try and figure out what UILabel is doing.  I added `Xtrace.h` and `Xtrace.mm` from the Xtrace git repository to Christian's UILabel demo project.  In `RootViewController.m`, I added `#import "Xtrace.h"`, and then experimented with various trace filters. Adding the following to RootViewController's `loadView`:

```
[Xtrace includeMethods:@"drawWithRect|drawInRect|drawTextInRect"];
[Xtrace traceClassPattern:@"String|UILabel|AppleLabel" excluding:nil];
```

Gives me this output:

```
| [<AppleLabel 0x7fedf141b520> drawTextInRect:{{0, 0}, {187.5, 333.5}}]
|  [<NSConcreteMutableAttributedString 0x7fedf160ec30>/NSAttributedString drawInRect:{{0, 156.5}, {187.5, 333.5}}]
| [<UILabel 0x7fedf1418dc0> drawTextInRect:{{0, 0}, {187.5, 333.5}}]
|  [<UILabel 0x7fedf1418dc0> _drawTextInRect:{{0, 0}, {187.5, 333.5}} baselineCalculationOnly:0]
|   [<__NSCFConstantString 0x1051d1db0>/NSString drawWithRect:{{0, 156.3134765625}, {187.5, 20.287109375}} options:1L attributes:<__NSDictionaryM 0x7fedf141ae00> context:<NSStringDrawingContext 0x7fedf15503c0>]
```

(I'm running this with Xcode 7.0 beta, iOS 9.0 simulator.)

We can see that Apple's implementation does not send `drawInRect:` to an NSAttributedString, but `drawWithRect:options:attributes:` to an NSString. I'm guessing these will end up doing the same.

We can also see exactly what the calculated Y offset is. In this initial position of the slider, it is 156.3134765625. It is interesting to note that it is not something that falls on some rounded integer value, or a  multiple of 0.25 or similar, which would otherwise be an explanation for the jumpiness.

We also see that UILabel sends 20.287109375 as the height, this is the same value as is calculated by `self.attributedText.size.height`. So it seems to be using that, though I haven't been able to trace that call (maybe it is using Core Text directly?).

So that's where I'm stuck.  Been trying to look at the difference between what UILabel calculates and the obvious formula "labelYOffset = (boundsHeight - labelHeight) / 2.0", but I find no consistent pattern.

**Update 1.**
So we can model this elusive Y offset as

> labelYOffset = (boundsHeight - labelHeight) / 2.0 + error

What the `error` is, is what we're trying to figure out. Let's try to study this like a scientist.  [Here](http://pastebin.com/E16cbHk7) is Xtrace output when I've dragged the slide to the end and then to the beginning. I also added an NSLog at each change of the slider which helps with separating the entries. I wrote [a Python script](https://gist.github.com/skagedal/e66309912058bb67e50a) to plot the error against the label height.

[image: Plot or UILabel error in vertical centering against label height]

Interesting.  We see that there's some linearity to the errors, but they strangely jump between the lines at certain points, if you understand what I mean.  What is going on here?  I'll be losing sleep until this is solved. :)

Comment: Well - you didn't *really* answer my question. But you a) taught me something new and b) gave me a way to at least be sure which y value Apple is using. -- I will try to figure out an appropriate formula to compute this value. The bounty is yours but I will not accept your answer because it doesn't answer my question. I will keep you updated if I find a matching formula.

Comment: Wow, thanks! :) And thank you for posting an interesting question, quite a mystery. I'm dissatisfied with not having cracked it and would love to get updated, I might actually have another go at it myself. Was thinking that I could analyze how the known variables relate more thoroughly, do some plotting.

Answer (score -2):

I dealt with this a lot in a stickering app I made.

I think the issue is probably not so much with UILabel as the font including the ascender and descenders. My assumption is that UILabel takes these values into consideration when it positions the body of the text which has an impact on the apparent vertical position. The problem with a whole lot of fonts is that these values are totally screwed up in the TTF / OTF file so you get e.g. clipping of the descender with .sizeToFit(), overlapping lines, wonky vertical position etc.

There are three ways to deal with this:

1) Use an NSAttributedString and more the baseline with NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName. TTTAttributedLabel is a good shortcut.

2) Use CoreText and CoreGraphics to render your own text layout in a CGLayer within a custom UIView subclass and effectively create your own UILabel equivalent. This is HARD!

3) Fix the font file so the baseline, ascender and descender are all correct.

Comment: You misunderstood my question. It is of no interest whether or not Apple does a good job of centering the text. I only want to understand their algorithm.